# Determining rate of interest

Tags: rates

If I have trade prices of 10Y futures contract (ZNH6) is it possible to derive the interest rate from it? Or is there a better way to obtain historical 10 year rates?

Comment: To go from futures price to interest rate on an actual govt bond is complicated and requires identifying the CTD (cheapest to deliver) bond which will not necessarily be the current 10 year bond.  (Future is based on a hypothetical bond which does not really trade, so Conversion Factors have to be applied to relate it to real bonds). If you just need to get historical 10 year bond rates there are better sources such as the Federal Reserve web site.

Comment: Thanks. Is there more "higher" frequency data? Say, every 10 minutes per day?

Comment: http://bondtutor.com/btchp5/topic2/topic2.htm may help. And googling "ZNH6" should show plenty of sites that give frequently updated near-real-time data.

Comment: @barrycarter T-bill futures are extinct. Bond futures are much more complex, and noob2 provided the correct answer. You have to identify the CTD first and then calculate the implied yield from there. Right now, the CTD for TY has ~7-year to maturity, you wouldn't be getting back a 10-year yield at all. It's much easier to get 10-year bond yields directly.